# HTML responsive image size

Tags: html, css, image

I have a `640*225` image I want it to fit on various device screens,
When I put `width="100%"` it fits perfectly on small device but on a PC it extends till it fits the entire browser width responsively.
Is there a way to set the actual image size on large screen and responsive when it hits the width size image?

Comment: Yes, it's called a [**media query**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). For further help, please update your question so that it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I'd also recommend referring to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and taking the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Try this: `img { max-width: 100%; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `width:100%; max-width:80%;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries to specify custom styles for every screen resolution. The most popular of them I put in the snippet below:

```css
/*==========  Desktop First Method  ==========*/

/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width : 1200px) {

}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {

}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {

}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {

}

/* Custom, iPhone Retina */
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {

}


/*==========  Mobile First Method  ==========*/

/* Custom, iPhone Retina */
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {

}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {

}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {

}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {

}

 /* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {

}
```

For more info about media queries:

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries
2. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp